# How add a icon in my TreeItem Material UI 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have a menu made with MATERIAL UI 4, it is composed of a first TreeItem with my main menu and a second TreeItem with my submenu.

I would like to add a specific icon to each label of the main menu.

How can I do ?

Is it possible that when I click on two drop-down menus, the first is reset by default ( no dropdown ).

```
    {stoMenu && (
      <TreeView
        style={test.menu}
      >
        {Menu.root.children.map(test=> {
          return (
            <TreeItem
              key={test.nodeId}
              nodeId={test.nodeId}
              label={test.text}
            >
              {test.children.map(child => {
                return (
                  <TreeItem
                    key={child.nodeId}
                    nodeId={child.nodeId}
                    label={child.text}
                  >
                    <Redirect to={child.id} />
                  </TreeItem>
                );
              })}
            </TreeItem>
          );
        })}
      </TreeView>
    )}
```

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if that helped you :)

Answer (score 6):

They have great example how to do that https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ui4dx

Also be careful with [TreeView](https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/#tree-view) component as it is still in [Lab](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/#about-the-lab)  and can be with some issues and not finished implementation.